# Get element name by containing text

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm looking through HTML documents for the text: "Required". What I need to find is the element that holds the text. For example:

```
<p>... Required<p>
```

I would get to element name = p

However, it might not be in a `<p>` tag. It could be in any kind of tag, which is where this question differs from some of the other search text Stack Overflow questions.

Right now I'm using:

```
page.at(':contains("Required")')
```

but this only get me the full HTML element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is the `:contains` pseudo class matches any element that has the searched for text anywhere in its descendants. You need to find the innermost element that contains such text. Since `html` is the ancestor of all elements, if the page contains the text anywhere then `html` will contain, and so that will be the first matching element.

I’m not sure you can achieve this with CSS, but you can use XPath like this:

```
page.at_xpath('//*[text()[contains(., "Required")]]')
```

This finds the first element node that has a `text()` node as a child that contains `Required`. When you have that node (if it exists) you can then call `name` on it to give the name of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS selectors:

```
page.css('p').text
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not trying to get the text, I'm trying to get the element name holding the text. So if it's <p>..."Required"</p>, I want to get p. If it's <td>...."Required"</td> I want to get td, etc.

Comment: How does this meet the requirement "...it might not be in a <p> tag. It could be in any kind of tag..."?

Answer (score 0):

For CSS you can do:

```
page.at('[text()*="Required"]')
```

It's not real CSS though, or even a jQuery extra.

Comment: `*=` is css, but `text()` isn't.